# How to use gallery in blackberry

Tags: java, blackberry

How to add images at the bottom of the screen Horizontally. and Slide these images to right to left and starting point if these images are Horizontally center of the screen.What should i use for this.

Here is the link for that scroll field Horizontal field manager.
http://appworld.blackberry.com/webstore/content/screenshots/56307/?lang=en
please click on this link and in that link u will see an image in that image at bottom show a horizontal filed manager with multiple images and focus image looking up from other images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add images at the bottom of screen horizontally you need a custom `VerticalFieldManager` that display on the bottom of the screen. You can achieved this overriding `sublayout` Method of the manager.
In this VerticalFieldManager you add one `HorizontalFieldManager` that contain all your Images.

For make images slide from right to left i have created a one custom `HorizontalFieldManager` in which the field added to that is scrolling from left to right.

```
public class CustomHorizontalField extends HorizontalFieldManager{

public boolean enableMoving = false;
private int focusOnIndex = 0;   

public void focusChangeNotify(int arg0) {

    super.focusChangeNotify(arg0);

    if(enableMoving)
    {
        int newFocusIndex = getFieldWithFocusIndex();
        if(newFocusIndex != focusOnIndex)
        {
            if( (newFocusIndex - focusOnIndex )> 0 )
            {
                startRotation(0, getFieldCount()-1);        
            }else
            {
                startRotation(getFieldCount()-1, 0);
            }
        }

    }else
    {
        focusOnIndex = getFieldWithFocusIndex();
    }

}
public int getPreferredWidth() {
    return Display.getWidth();
}
public int getPreferredHeight() {
    return super.getPreferredHeight();
}
protected void sublayout(int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {
    super.sublayout(Display.getWidth(), getPreferredHeight());
    setExtent(Display.getWidth(), getPreferredHeight());
}

private void startRotation(int from,int to)
{
    Field field = getField(from);
    delete(field);
    insert(field, to);
}   
}
```

Add your images to this `CustomHorizontalField` and add this manager to your custom `VerticalFieldManager` that display on the bottom of the screen.

**Edited**
Here is the code to create custom button that contain bitmap image in it.
you can set image to button that look like bitmap field and you can set `setChangeListener` for the button and add your code for what to do on click on image in override method `fieldChanged(Field field, int context)`.

```
public class CustomBitmapButtomField extends ButtonField{

   private  Bitmap activeBtn = null;
   private  Bitmap normalBtn = null;
   private  Bitmap focusBtn = null;

   private int btnHeight = 0;
   private int btnWidth = 0;


   public CustomBitmapButtomField(Bitmap normal,Bitmap focus,Bitmap active) {
   activeBtn = active;
   normalBtn = normal ;
   focusBtn = focus;
   btnWidth = normalBtn.getWidth();
   btnHeight = normalBtn.getWidth();
   setMargin(0, 0, 0, 0);
   setPadding(0,0,0,0);
   setBorder(BorderFactory.createSimpleBorder(new XYEdges(0, 0, 0, 0)));
   setBorder(VISUAL_STATE_ACTIVE, BorderFactory.createSimpleBorder(new XYEdges(0, 0, 0, 0)));
   setBackground(BackgroundFactory.createSolidBackground(Color.WHITE));   
   }

   protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
     Bitmap bitmap = null;
     switch (getVisualState()) {
    case VISUAL_STATE_NORMAL:
        bitmap = normalBtn;
        break;
    case VISUAL_STATE_FOCUS:
        bitmap = focusBtn;
        break;
    case VISUAL_STATE_ACTIVE:
        bitmap = activeBtn;
        break;
    default:
        bitmap = normalBtn;
        break;
    }
    graphics.drawBitmap(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), bitmap, 0, 0);
}

   public int getPreferredWidth() {
    return btnWidth;
}
   public int getPreferredHeight() {
    return btnHeight;
}
   protected void layout(int width, int height) {
    setExtent(btnHeight,btnHeight);
}
 }
```

Comment: I use that code but its not working.when i click on images it doesn't give any response

Comment: @cyberlinks you have to override `navigationClick` method for the BitmapField or you can create custom button that contain Bitmap in it and implement `FieldChangeListener` for the Button.

Comment: I have added code for the create custom button with bitmap.

Comment: hi right now i edit my question and add a new link please check this link and help me.